# Можно ли заменить оператор аргументом в функции? Если да, то как?

Tags: javascript

```
function math(x, y) {
    for (let i = x; i < y; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Мне нужно использовать цикл не только со знаком меньше и инкрементом, но и со знаком больше и декрементом.
Можно ли знак меньше и инкремент заменить принимаемыми функцией аргументами?
Или что можно сделать, чтобы не переписывать постоянно один и тот же цикл?

Comment: проще две функции сделать с постфиксом. mathByIncrement и mathByDecrement, чем что-то изголяться с текущей

Comment: А в целом, не вижу проблем в чём сложность каждый раз писать циклы)) программисты так делают каждый день)

Comment: В написании проблем никаких, просто так получилось, что есть несколько одинаковых циклов с разницей в операторах, вот я и задался этим вопросом)

Answer (score 2):

Если нет вероятности пролететь условие `i != y`, то можно просто передать `1/-1` в качестве слагаемого для `i`. Потому как условие `>` или `<` подразумевает `!=`плюс некоторую страховку пролететь момент если сравниваются дробные числа или инкремент/декремент - дробное или больше единицы. Если прибавляется или убавляется всегда единица, начальное значение i (значение `x`) - целое и `y` (операнд сравнения с i) - целое, то выражения равнозначны.

```js
function math1(x, y) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = x; i < y; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}

function math2(x,y) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = x; i > y; i--){
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}

function math(x,y,sign = 1){ // sign 1 (by default) -> "less than" and i++ or -1 -> "bigger than" and i--
    let arr = [];
    for(let i = x; i != y; i+= sign){
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(math1(0,5));
console.log(math2(5,0));

console.log(math(0,5));
console.log(math(5,0,-1));
```

Если доработать ответ [Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor), то функция будет работать как надо и при условии использования дробных чисел. То есть, количество шагов определяется переменной `j`, а `i` хранит правильную последовательность индексов (если это нужно для полного соответствия исходной функции).

```js
function math(x,y,sign = 1){ // sign 1 (by default) -> "less than" and i++ or -1 -> "bigger than" and i--
    let start = Math.min(x,y);
    let end = Math.max(x,y);
    
    let arr = [];
    for(let i = x, j = start; j < end; i += sign, j += Math.abs(sign)){
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(math(0,5));
console.log(math(5,0,-1));

console.log(math(0.5,5,0.5));
console.log(math(7.2,2,-1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно просто проверять в какую сторону цикл

```
function math(x, y, inc /*boolean*/ ) {
    for (let i = x; inc ? i < y : i > y; i += inc ? 1 : -1 ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Это намного проще и логичнее))

Answer (score 0):

```
function math(x, y) {
  let start = Math.min(x, y);
  let end = Math.max(x, y);
  for (let i = start, i < end; i++) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я решил воспользоваться вашим ответом)) Надеюсь, не в обиду...